# C# : How to stop streaminig media on flash content?

Tags: flash, streaming

I'm coding an application in C# that enters a site which contains flash embedded content. But every time a site is entered, the streaming movie starts to play automatically.
Is there anyway to stop automatic start of embedded content ?

I can't disable Flash since the entire site is coded in flash; all I want is to stop the embedded movie from playing.

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'd need to set a parameter in your embedded (HTML) object or the movie link, depending on the provider. For example, youtube has a similar notion with the autoplay parameter:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the source to the entire flash site. It might have been written to allow you to set a parameter which it will pay attention to, but most likely it wasn't. You then need to change the ActionScript to either listen to a parameter, or just do what you want (tell the embedded movie clip to `stop()` in the first frame) by default.